# Implementing gradient penalty loss with tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

Good morning,

I am trying to implement the improved WGAN for 1D data as described on this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00028.pdf

It has been implemented as an example in the keras-contrib github:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/examples/improved_wgan.py
Nevertheless, this implementation of the gradient penalty loss is not working anymore with tf2. K.gradients() returns [None].

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:505 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:467 train_step  **
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:143 __call__
        losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:246 call
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    <ipython-input-7-4f0896d0107b>:104 gradient_penalty_loss
        gradients_sqr = K.square(gradients)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:2189 square
        return math_ops.square(x)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:9964 square
        "Square", x=x, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:488 _apply_op_helper
        (input_name, err))

    ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Here it is the complete example of the issue:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11dcMKoiCigTnEn7QvmjqLNrJdmFztByT

Does anyone know what has changed? Any idea of how to solve this?

UPDATE: This ignores the error while constructing de computational graph. Then it seems to run

```
def gradient_penalty_loss(y_true, y_pred, averaged_samples):
  gradients = K.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
  try:
    gradients_sqr = K.square(gradients)
  except ValueError:
    print("Gradients returned None")
    return 0
  gradients_sqr_sum = K.sum(gradients_sqr, axis=np.arange(1, len(gradients_sqr.shape)))
  gradient_l2_norm = K.sqrt(gradients_sqr_sum)

  gradient_penalty = K.square(1 - gradient_l2_norm)

  return K.mean(gradient_penalty)
```

Nevertheless, I get incresingly high loss functions, is gradient_penalty_loss being ignored?
[image: Loss]

Comment: I'm looking at something very similar. It would be premature to promise anything, but I just managed to get rid of the error in question by disabling eager execution (`tensorflow.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`). If you did in fact need eager execution, then I think you'd need gradienttape instead. I won't write this as an answer just yet, but I figured if it were still blocking you then you might like something that might work soon rather than something that will work later.

Comment: Hello Josiah! Thank you for your answer, the problem seems to go in that direction. I managed to solve it catching the error and it seems like it only produces the error while constructing the computational graph. (I will post the code in the post). Then it seems to run fine! What I don't know is if ignoring the error while constructing the graph will make tensorflow just ignore the loss function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do what is proposed in the UPDATE, tf will just ignore the loss function

With Tensorflow 2, it seems imposible to to this the old way. I finally change the code to adapt it to this way of creating models. What I suggest?

1. Create the gen/disc models with keras
2. Join them extending tf.keras.Model class like the WGAN of : https://github.com/timsainb/tensorflow2-generative-models